# Dynamic redirect to different controllers

Tags: php, laravel-5

My application has some entities in db, and each one contains data about controller name.

When route is called it calls MainController and followed method which then redirects to different controllers.

Is there any better way of doing this?

UPDATE

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/print-pdf/{uniqueID}', Logic\EditorController@dispatchPDF');
```

EditorController.php

```
protected function dispatchPDF(Request $request, $uniqueID){
   $ent = Entity::find($uniqueID);
   $variable_name = $ent->controller_name;  //for example: LSEntityController
   return resolve("\App\Http\Controllers".$variable_name)->printPDF();
}
```

Then each entity has different controller:

LSEntityController.php

```
protected function printPDF(Request $request, $uniqueID){ 
   $pdf = \PDF::loadView('map.2017.print',array('data' => $data));
   $pdf->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
   return @$pdf->stream('data.pdf');
```

}

SOEntityController.php

```
 protected function printPDF(Request $request, $uniqueID){  

//here is the difference, this method must call some extra methods

   $this->compileAndReport();
   $pdf = \PDF::loadView('map.2017.print2',array('data' => $data));
   $pdf->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
   return @$pdf->stream('data.pdf'); 
}
```

Comment: why do your entities care about controllers?

Comment: Because entities require different data to print pdf.

Comment: Look at @Dees040's answer. Entities should know NOTHING about controllers. Your request should go through a router, which directs you to the controller, passing whatever along with it. The ideal controller should call a service which manipulates your data (your entity) and catch any exceptions and handle them, that's it.

Comment: I understand problem here, but how can I solve this dynamic controller redirection?

Answer (score 2):

Your entity shouldn't contain any information about a controller. It is best to let Laravel handle resolving controllers based on the request. An example of what you could do is:

Create a route for printing PDF to the browser.

```
Route::get('entities/{entity}/print', 'EntityController@print');
```

Then create a new controller with the following artisan command: `php artisan make:controller EntityController`.

The controller should look like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Entity;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EntityController extends Controller
{
    public function print(Entity $entity) 
    {

    }
}
```

Then in the `print` method you should create some code that prints the PDF. You could use a package for this, like [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).

**EDIT**

For your code you could update the `controller_name` row in your `entities` table to something like: `requires_compiling`, which could be a  [boolean](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#columns). Then if the entity requires to run extra methods before streaming a PDF you could do this:

```
protected function printPDF(Entity $entity)
{  
    if ($entity->requires_compiling) {
        $this->compileAndReport();
    }

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('map.2017.print2',array('data' => $data));
    $pdf->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');

    return @$pdf->stream('data.pdf'); 
}
```

Now you only need one controller for display the PDFs.

Comment: I agree that entity shouldn't contain information about controllers, but I didn't find any other way. Let's say it this way: each entity has different print method, with different data. My route is exactly like you suggested, but than maincontroller redirects to entity specific controller which contains print method. I don't like my code either, that's why I am asking for better solutions.

Comment: Can you update your answer and paste the code in your entity specific controllers. Then I can update my answer to your needs.

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Its nice solution, but yet, this way I will have to modify all 200+ entities and growing. I believe the project configuration is poorly configured from beginning, but it's hard to make big changes when application is already in production. Also I am moving logic from controllers to services.

Comment: Then use the values which are already there. Instead of `$entity->required_compiling` use `$entity->controller_name == 'SOEntityController.php'` in the `if` statement.

Comment: Yes, but than we are back to entities holding data about controllers. The point is that one route sometimes needs to call one controller, sometimes another. This was just simple example, there are others, more complex and with this approach methods would become quite messy. Thanks for help, but I am still not sure about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not send to one controller? Then switch the classname:

```
switch (get_class($entity)) {
    case 'ObjectA':
        $svc = new PdfPrintVersion1();
        $pdf = $svc->print($entity);
        break;
    case 'ObjectB':
        $svc = new PdfPrintVersion2();
        $pdf = $svc->print($entity);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Code is separated to different controllers for better control of methods (also there are many methods). I think that get_class methods will return class of entity not controller class.

Comment: then change the controllers into different service classes. in the controller, get the class name of the object, switch, then instantiate your service class (former controller). pass in the entity, get your pdf output back, and in your controller send to the view

Comment: That solution works for different classes, but this entity has always same class but sometimes needs to call different controllers.

Comment: maybe you should have an abstract class, and extend several classes for each different use case.Possibly a factory class which figures out which class the object should be created as.

Comment: So actually inside factory I would have switch to decide which class to return?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea! figure out what to return, create and return it! Then you can use the above method :-)

Comment: I will give it a try.